# How to detect, which of features binded on hot-keys Ctrl+Shift in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, kali-linux, dconf, gsettings, options

Kali 2016.2 in Qemu:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64  -boot d -m 5000 --enable-kvm 
-cdrom kali-linux-2016.2-amd64.iso
```

I'm trying to bind switcher to Russian Language in Gnome:

1. dconf:

   ```
   /usr/bin/dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll']"
   ```
2. Using `dconf-editor`, everything seems fine.
3. gsettings(Optionally):

   ```
   /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us+mac'),('xkb','ru+mac')]"
   ```

Nothing works. However, I can click on the `button` in right-top corner.

`Keyboard`->`Typing`->`Switch to next input source`: here, I can not setup <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. I can setup <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Seems, this combination of hot-keys locked by something else. I've looked around, checked all tabs.

Moreover, I've checked all Gnome's configuration tools, like:

1. `dconf-editor` ( Just visually )
2. `/usr/bin/dconf dump /`
3. `gsettings list-schemas`
4. `gconftool -R /`
5. `gconftool-2 --dump /`
6. `update-alternatives --get-selections`

I'm "grepping" everything by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and by <kbd>Shift</kbd>... There is no any combination which may lock this switching.

How to setup <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch Languages? And how to find this place, where is locked?

Comment: Having the same problem. Loks like the Shift key is considered as a pure modifer an cannot be used without a letter. Have you found a solution using dconf?